# Is assigning two variables to items in the same list the best way to access and perform operations on those items?

Tags: python

Say I have a list

```
l = [1,2,3]
```

and I want to sum each item in the list with every other item in the list. I could do this:

```
x = [(a, b) for a in l for b in l]
y = [(a + b) for a in l for b in l]

x = [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
y = [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6]
```

Is assigning two variables (`a` and `b`) to items in the same list (`l`) the best way to access and perform operations on those items? Is there a better way to do this?

I've looked at list methods and functions, and couldn't find any.

**UPDATE**

Many people recommended the itertools product function so I thought I'd include timings before I mark as answered:

```
mysetup = """
from itertools import product
l = [10, 15, 3, 7]
k = 17
"""
mycode = """
[i for i in product(l, repeat=2)]
"""

t = timeit.timeit(setup=mysetup, stmt=mycode, number=100000)
# 0.1505305


mysetup2 = """
l = [10, 15, 3, 7]
k = 17
"""
mycode2 = """
[(a, b) for a in l for b in l]
"""

t1 = timeit.timeit(setup=mysetup2, stmt=mycode2, number=100000)
# 0.1432976
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python provides built in method

```
from itertools import product
l = [1,2,3]
```

Then generate the sum using list comprehension in a single step to be more efficent

```
result= [sum(i) for i in product(l, repeat= 2) ]

#result=[2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> [sum(combination) for combination in list(product(l, repeat = 2))]
[2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: `combinations_with_replacement` doesn't produce the same values as what the OP wanted. You should use `product` instead - but timing it show that it is slower than the code in the question.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thanks for pointing out. Answer was updated by using `product`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) based approach:

```
from operator import add
from itertools import product, starmap
l = [1,2,3]

list(starmap(add, product(l, repeat=2)))
# [2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

Let's check the *timings*:

```
l = list(range(1000))

%timeit list(map(sum, product(l, repeat=2)))
# 187 ms ± 14.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit [sum(combination) for combination in combinations_with_replacement(l, 2)]
# 123 ms ± 4.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

list(starmap(add, product(l, repeat=2)))
# 102 ms ± 4.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: `combinations_with_replacement` doesn't produce the same values as `product` - it doesn't yield the pairs in reverse order, that's why it's about twice as fast...

Comment: Thank you for pointing out @ThierryLathuille, indeed here we want the cartesian product

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which gets every combination of a sequence:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> list(product(l, repeat=2))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
>>> list(map(sum, product(l, repeat=2)))
[2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6]
>>>
```